# Individual function works but adding a variable from another function doesn't

Tags: c

I got the code to run through without any problems until it comes down to calculating the total price of a package. Essentially it's a package selection that you input the hours into and it calculates the total price for whichever selection was made. The individual package functions work on their own (I just took the code and added another int and scanf for input). However whenever it goes through the entire process of the larger code the int from inputHours is not correctly transferred over. I went ahead and took out package B and C just to make the code simpler. I want to figure out how to get package A to work and model the other two off of that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int inputHours()
{
    int hours;
    char hours_verify;

    do
    {
        do
        {
            printf("Number of hours from 0 to 720: ");
            scanf(" %i", &hours);
        }while(hours<0||hours>720);
        
        printf("%i hours, correct?\n", hours);
        printf("Y/N\n");
        scanf(" %c", &hours_verify);
        
    }while(toupper((unsigned char)hours_verify) != 'Y');
    
    printf("%i hours of internet were used.\n", hours);
}

int pkgA(int hours)
{
    int pkgprice= 15; //The package price under 50 hours
    int extra_price= 2; //Price per hour over 50 hours

    if(hours<=50) //Price under 50 hours
    {
        printf("The total price is:$%i", pkgprice);
    }
    else if(hours<=720) //Calculate anything over 50 hours
    {
        int extra_hours=hours - 50;
    
        float total_price=extra_hours * extra_price + pkgprice;
        printf("The total price is:$%.2f", total_price);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    char package_choice;
    char package_verify;

    do
    {
        do{
            printf("Which package would you like to select? A, B, or C ");
            scanf(" %c", &package_choice);
        }while(toupper((unsigned char)package_choice) != 'A' 
               && toupper((unsigned char)package_choice) != 'B' 
               && toupper((unsigned char)package_choice) != 'C');
        
        printf("You chose %c, correct?\n", package_choice);
        printf("Y/N\n");

        scanf(" %c", &package_verify);
    }while(toupper((unsigned char)package_verify) != 'Y');

    printf("You chose package %c.\n", package_choice);
    
    inputHours;
    int hours=inputHours();
    
    switch(package_choice)
    {
    case 'A':
        pkgA(hours);
        break;
        
    case 'B':
        pkgB(hours);
        break;
        
    case 'C':
        pkgC(hours);
        break;
    }
}
```

I have switched "int hours" with "int inputhours()" in a number of places to see if that might have been it, retested the individual code (again with a int hours and a scanf just to see if it worked the way it was supposed to) with no issues. Sometimes I get the code to say "The total price is $15" when it should have been more (ie. for 51 hours it should be $17).

Comment: The `inputHours()` function doesn't return anything. You should have gotten a warning when you compiled this.

Comment: Put `return hours;` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, your `inputHours` function doesn't have a return. You want to return `hours` at the end of the function.

```
int inputHours()
{
    int hours;
    char hours_verify;

    do
    {
        do
        {
            printf("Number of hours from 0 to 720: ");
            scanf(" %i", &hours);
        }while(hours<0||hours>720);
        
        printf("%i hours, correct?\n", hours);
        printf("Y/N\n");
        scanf(" %c", &hours_verify);
        
    }while(toupper((unsigned char)hours_verify) != 'Y');
    
    printf("%i hours of internet were used.\n", hours);

    return hours;
}
```

Now when you use the following, the value you expect will be assigned to the local variable `hours` in `main`.

> ```
>     int hours=inputHours();
> ```

Comment: Does the return hours; essentially just tell the code to transfer the integer (or whatever number is input) back to main?

Comment: It's returning the value in `hours` to `main` yes. The fact that the variables have the same name is irrelevant. The variable in `inputHours` could be named `joeyJoeJoeJrShabadoo`.

Comment: Ahhhh, that makes complete sense. I was under the impression that anything after "return" was supposed to guide you to a different code or function. This is my first "big" code to put together and it's been giving me a hell of a ride so far haha. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to correct is to return a value from `inputHours()` (credit @Barmar).

Then, if you want to replicate a version that works, there's this:

```
void pkgA( int hours ) { // nothing is returned, so "void"
    double cost = 15; // use "double" instead of "float"

    if( hours > 50 ) // only deal with "excess hours" case
        cost += (hours - 50) * 2.0; // add excess cost to the base cost

    printf( "The total price is:$%.2f", cost ); // a single print statement
}
```

This example is smaller, meaning your code will be smaller and easier to maintain.

Eventually, you might try to combine the 3 functions into one and deal with the 3 different constants as parameters to that function. For example:

```
double pkg( int hours, int baseHrs, double cost, double excess ) {
    if( hours > baseHrs )
        cost += (hours - baseHrs) * excess;
    return cost;
}
```

---

**EDIT** (new section)
Bringing forward a previous response to this OP, here's one way to validate user input:

```
#include <string.h>
//...
    do {
        // Prompt for package choice and get input...
    } while( !strchr( "ABCabc", package_choice ) );
```

---

Now, on to the processing:

```
double val = 0; // another variable

// ...
switch(package_choice) {
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
        val = pkg( hours, 50, 15.0, 2.0 );
        break;

    case 'B':
    case 'b':
        val = pkg( hours, 100, 30.0, 1.5 );
        break;

    case 'C':
    case 'c':
        val = pkg( hours, 200, 60.0, 1.0 );
        break;
    }
    printf( "The total price of '%c' is:$%.2f", package_choice, val );
// ....
```

Comment: You are constantly showing me different ways to write up and condense my code. Thank you for everything, seriously. My professor has yet to respond to any of my messages this whole semester and I have seriously struggled trying to understand what and how to write up code this whole time.

Comment: As @Barmar noted, the compiler should have told you "missing return value from function" (or some such.) The compiler is your best friend; always guiding you toward potential problems in code. Heed its judgements. As for "condense", 'experience and experimenting' (with the help of the compiler) will help you learn lots of data processing "shortcuts"... Just keep on keepin' on... :-)

Comment: So I do have a follow up question. I made the changes and now package A works but B and C don't display the total price at the end. I went to the debug section and followed it along the same way with the same selection and input, but that time it did display the "total price..." at the end of it. Exited the debug and tried again, it wouldn't display that for whatever reason. Package B and C are essentially the same code as A just different variables. Is there any specific reason why it won't display that you can think of off the top of your head?

Comment: The three options represent three different straight line graphs... Basic geometry: `y=mx+b`... Given the package costs and the rate for exceeding base hours, perhaps you can determine the number of hours of 'A' at which point it would be cheaper to chose 'B' instead. Likewise, at what 'usage' of 'B' would 'C' cost less to purchase? Just a fun exercise... :-)

Comment: Follow up to the previous question: I copied and repasted the code back into everything and redid the variables, it works now both with the debug and normally. I'm not sure what was different because they were essentially the same code

Comment: Glad for the latest news... :-) Coding REQUIRES attention to detail... Can't say what changed, but I'm glad you've got something working. ALWAYS SAVE A COPY of what works before making further changes... Always having one (partially) working version "in the bank" will save you many, many hours of stress.

Comment: So playing around with the code you typed up I can get it all to work except the output for the total price is always 0?

Comment: @jtward17 Just a hunch: If you use my suggested `strchr()` to validate `package_choice`, you will need to add `case 'a': case 'A':` to the switch options (and 'b', 'B'...) Hard to diagnose without seeing the current state of the code... :-)

Comment: That makes sense. I went through and tested the code again but one with only capital letters and one with lower case. If they were all capital letters it worked fine, if it was lowercase it would output 0 again. I don't seem to be able to find the strchr() comment (unless I'm overlooking it). What does that do for the code itself, as in why would that be significant? Sorry for the many questions you're just the first one to actually explain most things to me

Comment: @jtward17 I've "brought forward" the relevant version of verifying user input. Note, this version does not alter the case of the character entered, so I've also added 3 more `case` statements to the `switch()` to deal with both upper & lower case user entry.